# React conditional toggle working only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the project i am working on, I am trying to implement a Hamburger Menu functionality using React. I decided to toggle a boolean (useHamburger) using the function TurnToHamburger. These would change the stylesheet of the navbar so that it would look like a dropdown menu. Problem is, it would only toggle once and after that the appearance of the navbar does not change at all. How do i solve this?

Below is the relevant code.

```
import {useState} from 'react'
const Navbar = ({img}) => {
   const navbarinitial = {
    listStyle: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    flexDirection:'row',
    width: '30%',
    color: 'var(--GrayishViolet)'
   };

   const navbarfinal = {
    listStyle: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection:'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    width: '30%',
    color: 'var(--GrayishViolet)',
    backgroundColor:'red'
   }

   let useHamburger = false;
   const [navbarstyle, setNavbarStyle] = useState(navbarinitial);



   const TurnToHamburger=()=> {

       if (!useHamburger) {
        setNavbarStyle(navbarfinal)
        useHamburger = true;
       }
       else {
           setNavbarStyle(navbarinitial)
           useHamburger = false;
       }
   }
```

Comment: I think you have things the wrong way round. The state of the hamburger should be in state instead of your CSS. Also: iirc `useHamburger` is tripping you up because `use[word]` is a sort of a reserved keyword that React uses when it looks for hooks. I maybe wrong on that point tho.

Comment: just remove the "useHamburger "variable and define it using "useState" hook.

Comment: @novonimo this answer somehow works, though i am unsure of what the difference between manual boolean toggling and useState toggling is

Comment: @Andy i dont think thats the case for the second statement. I renamed it to something else that doesnt have the use keyword yet the error persisted.  However, seems like your first answer did the trick. Thank you

Comment: Yeah @KevinH it was just a vague feeling that I'd read about that somewhere, but it also makes sense. `use[word]` in React has a specific purpose and you'll just muddle your code up if you use it for anything other than hooks. Glad to help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In the `useState()` hold the current status of the menu (`hamburger`). The state should be a Boolean - hamburger open or not. Toggle this state to change the menu. The selection of the style object should be derived from the current value of the `hamburger` state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const navbarinitial = {
  listStyle: "none",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-around",
  flexDirection: "row",
  width: "30%",
  color: "var(--GrayishViolet)",
};

const navbarfinal = {
  listStyle: "none",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "space-around",
  width: "30%",
  color: "var(--GrayishViolet)",
  backgroundColor: "red",
};

const Navbar = () => {
  const [hamburger, setHamburger] = useState(false);

  const toggleHamburger = () => setHamburger((prev) => !prev);

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="nav-right">
        <ul
          className="nav-options"
          style={hamburger ? navbarfinal : navbarinitial}
        >
          <li>Features</li>
          <li>Pricing</li>
          <li>Resources</li>
        </ul>
        <div className="navbar-buttons">
          <button onClick={toggleHamburger}>Toggle Burger</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, root);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work is because any variable that doesn't use useState will be reset each time the component renders. Do this instead:

```
const [hamburger_open, setHamburgerOpen] = useState(false);

const TurnToHamburger=()=> {
   if (!hamburger_open) {
       setNavbarStyle(navbarfinal);
       setHamburgerOpen(true);
   } else {
       setNavbarStyle(navbarinitial);
       setHamburgerOpen(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer works, although i am still unsure of what the difference is between my code

Comment: The difference is that you were setting the value of useHamburger to false each time the component rendered. When you set the value by using useState, the value persists between renderings. I do recommend that you take a look at Ori Drori's answer too, though, because you don't need to put navbarstyle in a useState, an if-statement would suffice.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: @novonimo Yeah, I know. I'll add an explanation to it.

Answer (score -1):

const toggleHamburger = () => setHamburger(!prev);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).